# AngularJS NgMap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with NgMap. I want to create two markers as soon as user complete typing place name in input. There are two inputs for two localization - I am using google autocomplete. After typing I am getting response with long and lat of localization. 
I set watches on inputs as below:

```
  $scope.$watch(function ($scope) { return $scope.locationFrom }, function () {
        if (angular.isDefined($scope.locationFrom)) {
            vm.geopositionFrom = $scope.locationFrom;
            vm.cos = $scope.locationFrom.geometry.location.lat().toString() + "," + $scope.locationFrom.geometry.location.lng().toString();
        }
    });
```

Finally in the view I am using vm.cos as attribute of position

```
 <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]">
            <marker position="vm.cos"></marker>
 </ng-map>
```

In vm.cos I am having correct long and lat separated with ",".

This solution is not working however when I set static position e.g

```
<marker position="-25.363882,131.044922"></marker>
```

It works as supossed.

Anyone have any idea?

PS. I am using https://ngmap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to put marker on the position user types.
 For that you won't need watch as angularjs does auto-binding. 
 You can refer following code.

 **Script Required**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng-map.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<ng-map center="{{mapCenter}}" zoom="13"> 
     <marker animation="DROP" position="{{mapCenter}}"> </marker>
 </ng-map>
 <input places-auto-complete types="['geocode']" on-place-changed = "myCallback(place)" 
ng-model="mapCenter" component-restrictions="{country:'in'}" />
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.mapCenter="pune";
NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    console.log(map.getCenter());
    console.log('markers', map.markers);
});
```